# Does the empty set exist?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Does the empty set exist?

I don't think it exists

because

If there are no constituent elements of an object, it can be said that the object does not exist.

Can't this be the reason why the empty set does not exist?

Comment: Yes, it does. "In [axiomatic set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_empty_set), the axiom of empty set is a statement that asserts the existence of a set with no elements." In mathematics, any consistent object can be declared to exist by postulation. And any object whose existence can then be derived from axioms exists as well. That is just the convention for using the word "exist" in mathematics.

Comment: @Conifold I'm using a translator, but I don't understand. Are you saying that could be the reason why the empty set doesn't exist?

Comment: @Conifold It is really true that objects do not exist, but why does mathematics say that something that does not exist exists?

Comment: I am saying that whether it "exists" or not is decided by convention. Conventions are adopted for pragmatic reasons, such as technical convenience, there are no "higher" reasons beyond that. It is not like empty set, number 1 or any other mathematical abstraction exists "in reality", so "really true" (or not) is meaningless in this case.

Comment: @Conifold I'm so sorry, but I think all math is bullshit.

Comment: Tell it to the device you are using to access this site, it was developed using a lot of math.

Comment: @Conifold I know I say the same thing because I'm stupid.
Is it false that objects without constituent elements do not exist?

Comment: On many conceptions, yes, it is false. If you keep breaking things up into constituents you'll eventually have to stop at something that has no constituents. For example, elementary particles in modern physics are taken to have no constituents.  But "exist" is a [polysemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) word, it does not mean much in particular outside of specific contexts, and then it means different things. There are physical, mathematical, platonic, metaphysical, etc., existences. People often disagree as to whether this or that does or does not exist in each case.

Comment: @Conifold So what perspective is it that says objects don't exist?

Comment: Which objects? Generally, [anti-realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-realism) about something is the position that objects talked about in that something do not "really" exist.

Comment: @Conifold “An object without constituent elements”

Comment: If a box is empty, why doesn't the box still exist? You might say, "What the box is made of, makes it exist," but then the empty set is made of the inset function (so to speak), so it would still exist, too. Anyway, constituents and elements are not the same thing, constituents are more like subsets than elements, and the empty set does have one subset, itself.

Comment: What about {∅} (the set containing the empty set)? If a set contains an element, but that element doesn't exist, does the set exist?

Comment: @benrg I don't think the set exists

Comment: You could just choose to accept that it exists on the basis of a conventionally accepted set of axioms. A more pragmatic approach would be to say that it is convenient to accept that the empty set exists. If we do not accept it, lots of equations in mathematics become awkward, because we have to constantly make exceptions for the empty case. That said, there is a small minority of mathematicians who do not accept the existence of the empty set. Usually they do not accept that zero is a number - the two tend to go together.

Comment: This question simply hinges upon what it means to exist,  and therefore is metaontological. Id simply reply that an empty box exists even if it's empty. See SEPs article Abstract Objects

Answer (score 2):

The empty sets existence ( in ZF) is secured by two axioms. Whether it exists as some kind of platonic object is another concern. The empty set appears in a diverse set of contexts, and so there is at least argument for its utility.

I'll make the ZF argument, so you can at least see what most people mean when they say the empty set exists.

Axiom 1: Set Existence  - " There exists a set"

```
∃x(x=x)
```

Axiom 2. Subset Axiom Scheme - "Subclasses of Sets, are  Sets"

For y not free in φ i.e. φ  doesn't say anything about y

```
∀x∃y∀z(z∈y ↔ φ(z) and z∈x)
```

Putting these two together + basic logic

We get:

By Axiom 1 pick x s.t. x = x

Let φ(z) be the formula z ≠ z

Apply Axiom 2

∃y∀z(z∈y ↔ φ(z) and z∈x)

∃y∀z(z∈y ↔ z ≠ z and z∈x)

Specialize y

∀z(z∈y ↔ z ≠ z and z∈x)

As a basic axiom of equality everything is equal to itself. - More formally, we could include another axiom- extentionality which ensures all sets are equal to themselves.

So, by our Axioms

y = {z∈x | z ≠ z } exists  and by the definition of equality, there are no such z's.

So, we have an empty set.

Answer (score 2):

The existence of the empty set is axiom-dependent. In typical axioms (ZF, ETCS) the empty set exists. However, there are consistent logics without an empty set. For example, take Leinster's presentation of ETCS ([Leinster 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6543)) and remove axiom 3. Then, there is no way to construct the empty set from coproducts without appealing to higher category theory; the axioms themselves are not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'exist' has many meanings, so whether the empty set exists depends on which meaning of the word exist you have in mind. In mathematics, the word 'exist' can be used in a phrase such as ' three solutions exist' to refer to abstract objects that are consistent with the applicable axioms and rules, so in that sense of the word the empty set exists.

Answer (score 1):

If no set of elements was empty, then whatever the types of whichever elements there were, every type would have at least one token. For example, if the set of unicorns isn't empty, then there is at least one unicorn; if the set of deities isn't empty, then there is at least one deity; and so on and on. Now, *the* empty set, of set-theoretic lore *per se nota*, is a set that is empty of other sets, whereas for 1 = {0} = {{}}, 1 is a set with one set in it ("the" empty one). So if the empty set didn't exist, then 1 would have a set as an element that wasn't empty as such, either, and then *that* set wouldn't be empty, and so on and on, so that 1 would turn out in von Neumann format to have arbitrarily many elements and subsets, or in Zermelo format just arbitrarily many subsets, neither conclusion being especially appealing, here (it seems "morally false," in the mathematical sense of that phrase, to claim that 1, as an ordinal set, is infinite, although we might imagine that it has infinitely many possible parts *as a number*, e.g. 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc.).